# Find a space whose dual does not separate points

Tags: functional-analysis

I read about the fact that for a locally convex topological vector space $X$, its dual $X^*$ separates points, i.e. for any $x\neq y$ in $X$, $\exists f \in X^*$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Could you help me to find a non locally convex topological vector space such that its dual does not separate points? Thanks

Comment: Do you know any non-locally-convex topological vector spaces? If so, which ones?

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually I don't know any such space

Comment: @PhoemueX You forgot to say which $p$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can equip $L^p([0,1])$ with the metric $\|f-g\|^p_p = \displaystyle \int_0^1 |f(t) - g(t)|^p \, dt$ if $0 < p < 1$. It is a (fairly) well-known result due to Mahlon M. Day that the only bounded linear functional on this space is  the zero functional. In particular, the space is not locally convex.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen this example several days ago. Then I forget it

Comment: Interesting. I know next to nothing about non-Banach functional analysis (not to mention non-locally convex), so it's kind of surprising to me. +1. :)